# Make MYSQL query shorter but with the same result

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table in which the possible value is null, 0(not ok), 1(ok) and 3(not/applicable). I have to select only the null and the value equal to 1 in strict order. The query I have is to long. Can you plese help me to make it shorter.

```
 create table cv.cv_interview_status
(
    id                    int auto_increment
        primary key,
    type                  varchar(255)                       not null,
    date                  varchar(255)                       not null,
    issue                 varchar(255)                       not null,
    recruiter             varchar(255)                       not null,
    department            varchar(255)                       not null,
    position              varchar(255)                       not null,
    feedback_department   tinyint                            null,
    contacted_hr          tinyint                            null,
    office_interview      tinyint                            null,
    department_testing    tinyint                            null,
    department_acceptance tinyint                            null,
    add_cv                tinyint                            null,
    psychological_test    tinyint                            null,
    department_interview  tinyint                            null,
    accepted_not_accepted tinyint                            null,
    salary_request_to_ceo tinyint                            null,
    ceo_feedback          tinyint                            null,
    salary_offer          tinyint                            null,
    accept_salary_offer   tinyint                            null,
    hr_documentation      tinyint                            null,
    hr_legal_requirements tinyint                            null,
    date_created          datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
);

    SELECT *
    FROM cv_interview_status
    WHERE 1
      AND (
            (`feedback_department` IS NULL)
            OR
            (
                    `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` IS NULL
                    AND `office_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `department_testing` IS NULL
                    AND `department_acceptance` IS NULL
                    AND `add_cv` IS NULL
                    AND `psychological_test` IS NULL
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `department_testing` IS NULL
                    AND `department_acceptance` IS NULL
                    AND `add_cv` IS NULL
                    AND `psychological_test` IS NULL
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` = 1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` IS NULL
                    AND `department_acceptance` IS NULL
                    AND `add_cv` IS NULL
                    AND `psychological_test` IS NULL
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` IS NULL
                    AND `add_cv` IS NULL
                    AND `psychological_test` IS NULL
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` IS NULL
                    AND `psychological_test` IS NULL
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` IS NULL
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` IS NULL
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` = 1
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` = 1
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` = 1
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` = 1
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` = 1
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` = 1
                    AND `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` = 1
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` = 1
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` = 1
                    AND `ceo_feedback` = 1
                    AND `salary_offer`IS NULL
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` = 1
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` = 1
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` = 1
                    AND `ceo_feedback` = 1
                    AND `salary_offer` = 1
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
            OR
            (
                        `feedback_department` = 1
                    AND `contacted_hr` =1
                    AND `office_interview` = 1
                    AND `department_testing` = 1
                    AND `department_acceptance` = 1
                    AND `add_cv` = 1
                    AND `psychological_test` = 1
                    AND `department_interview` = 1
                    AND `accepted_not_accepted` = 1
                    AND `salary_request_to_ceo` = 1
                    AND `ceo_feedback` = 1
                    AND `salary_offer` = 1
                    AND `accept_salary_offer` = 1
                    AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                    AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
                )
        );
```

The filter for this table works perfect, but the query is to long, can you give me an advise how can I refactor it?

The solution:

```
 SELECT
    *
FROM
    cv_interview_status
WHERE
    ( `feedback_department` IS NULL )
   OR (
            `feedback_department` = 1
        AND (
            (      IFNULL( `contacted_hr`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `office_interview`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `department_testing`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `department_acceptance`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `add_cv`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `psychological_test`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `department_interview`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `accepted_not_accepted`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `salary_request_to_ceo`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `ceo_feedback`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `salary_offer`, 1 )
                  * IFNULL( `accept_salary_offer`, 1 )

                ) = 1 )
        AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
        AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would help if you would explain what you are trying to achieve with the query - sometimes it gives a better understanding of what you can do.

Comment: Remove `1 AND (`. It will significantly reduce length of query. Other than that - have query generating script if needed

Comment: Yes @NigelRen asked we need more information. Mean while you can rey this
`SELECT *
FROM cv_interview_status
WHERE
    (
        feedback_department IS NULL
        OR
        (
            feedback_department = 1
            AND COALESCE(
                contacted_hr, office_interview,
                department_testing, department_acceptance, add_cv,
                psychological_test, department_interview, accepted_not_accepted,
                salary_request_to_ceo, ceo_feedback, salary_offer,      accept_salary_offer, hr_documentation, hr_legal_requirements) IS NULL));`

Comment: @NigelRen it's not the same result, it select only one row

Comment: @Justinas I know, but in this way we are adding query

Comment: This looks like an employee onboarding tracker where a 3 at any stage indicates that the application is not proceeding and not required in result so it may be possible to invert the logic by filtering on cancellations alone, You could simplify this by providing sample data for 3 stages for 4 candidates with a cancellation and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Would a disjunction of multiple `column IN (NULL, 1)` be satisfactory?

Comment: @Vivick I've tried but it's not ok

Comment: @Olga, please could you give me the create table script with insert statments so I can try it and let you know

Comment: @SenthilPNathan I add it my question

Comment: @Olga still i havent got the insert script, if you could add that too.
Meanwhile check this
`SELECT * FROM cv_interview_status
WHERE COALESCE( feedback_department,
        contacted_hr,
        office_interview,
        department_testing,
        department_acceptance,
        add_cv,
        psychological_test,
        department_interview,
        accepted_not_accepted,
        salary_request_to_ceo,
        ceo_feedback,
        salary_offer,
        accept_salary_offer,
        hr_documentation,
        hr_legal_requirements
    ) IS NULL
OR feedback_department = 1;`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan it select all values (0,1,3)

Comment: @olga do you just need 1? can you message or chat here so I can copy you the query we need some clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
...
WHERE ...
  AND CONCAT( COALESCE(feedback_department, 0),
              COALESCE(contacted_hr, 0),
              ...
              COALESCE(hr_legal_requirements, 0)
              ) REGEXP '^1{1,}0{2,}$'
...
```

> I need the query which select only value 1 (ok) and null, but you query select and the value 0(not ok) – Olga

Simply use another replacement for NULLs. For example

```
...
WHERE ...
  AND CONCAT( COALESCE(feedback_department, 'N'),
              COALESCE(contacted_hr, 'N'),
              ...
              COALESCE(hr_legal_requirements, 'N')
              ) REGEXP '^1{1,}N{2,}$'
...
```

Comment: the query select the value 0-zero too, but it is very good approach

Comment: @Olga *the query select the value 0-zero too* ?? I don't understand what you tell about. CONCAT converts your flags to single string then checks that this string contains at least one starting 1 and at least two trailing 0's (according to your SQL code). What do you mean with '0-zero'?

Comment: I need the query which select only value 1 (ok) and null, but you query select and the value 0(not ok)

Comment: @Olga Oh, I see. Wait... updated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works out:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    cv_interview_status
WHERE
    (`feedback_department` IS NULL
        OR (`feedback_department` = 1
        AND (`contacted_hr` IS NULL
        OR `office_interview` IS NULL
        OR `department_testing` IS NULL
        OR `department_acceptance` IS NULL
        OR `add_cv` IS NULL
        OR `psychological_test` IS NULL
        OR `department_interview` IS NULL
        OR `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
        OR `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
        OR `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
        OR `salary_offer` IS NULL
        OR `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
        OR `hr_documentation` IS NULL
        OR `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL))
        
        AND NOT (`feedback_department` = 1
        AND (`contacted_hr` IS NULL
        OR `office_interview` IS NULL
        OR `department_testing` IS NULL
        OR `department_acceptance` IS NULL
        OR `add_cv` IS NULL
        OR `psychological_test` IS NULL
        OR `department_interview` IS NULL
        OR `accepted_not_accepted` IS NULL
        OR `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NULL
        OR `ceo_feedback` IS NULL
        OR `salary_offer` IS NULL
        OR `accept_salary_offer` IS NULL
        OR `hr_documentation` IS NULL
        OR `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL)
        
        AND (`contacted_hr` IS NOT NULL
        OR `office_interview` IS NOT NULL
        OR `department_testing` IS NOT NULL
        OR `department_acceptance` IS NOT NULL
        OR `add_cv` IS NOT NULL
        OR `psychological_test` IS NOT NULL
        OR `department_interview` IS NOT NULL
        OR `accepted_not_accepted` IS NOT NULL
        OR `salary_request_to_ceo` IS NOT NULL
        OR `ceo_feedback` IS NOT NULL
        OR `salary_offer` IS NOT NULL
        OR `accept_salary_offer` IS NOT NULL
        OR `hr_documentation` IS NOT NULL
        OR `hr_legal_requirements` IS NOT NULL)));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    tt 
WHERE
    ( `a` IS NULL ) 
    OR (
        `a` = 1 
      AND ( ( IFNULL( `b`, 1 ) * IFNULL( `c`, 1 ) * IFNULL( `d`, 1 )) = 1 ) 
    )
```

Comment: it select value 3 and 0 too

Comment: check out the new idea above

Comment: and the  AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL how to add, the columns names should be null

Comment: till the hr_documentation and hr_legal_requirments it work perfect

Comment: I simply add AND `hr_documentation` IS NULL
                  AND `hr_legal_requirements` IS NULL to the end and now it work perfect